# Detecting if a listener has been registered

Tags: java, android

How can I detect if a new listener has been registered for any widget in my android app? Is there a place where I can intercept the listener when it's being registered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding but you could do something like:

```
public interface ListenerChangeListener { // Feel free to remove the redundancy :P
    public void listenerAdded(ListenerChangeEvent e);
    public void listenerRemoved(ListenerChangeEvent e);
}
```

And

```
public class ListenerChangeEvent extends AWTEvent // or other class {
    // Implementation
}
```

Finally, subclass your own custom widgets and modify the `addXListener()` and `removeXListener()` methods to fire your custom events if any have been added to the component. Then you just create your "Listener" class as per normal and implement your new Listener interface and so on.

It's a bit long and drawn out, again, I may have misunderstood exactly what you were after.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of listeners on an object through a getter method (e.g. `getActionListeners ()` on `AbstractButton`), and check if the one you have added is in the list.

Comment: does this apply for all widgets or only buttons ?

Comment: On a button widget, you can call methods like `getOnFocusChangeListener()`, or `getKeyListener()`. Every widget probably have similar methods (I haven't used the Android SDK).